# return BehaviorSubject after receive Observable from a serveer

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables, behaviorsubject

```
  getWatchlist(query: string): BehaviorSubject<IWatchlist> {
    this.search(query)
      .subscribe((searchResults: Observable<ISearchResults>) => {
        const watchlist = formatSearchResults(searchResults);
        this.watchlist$.next(watchlist);
      });
    return this.watchlist$;
  }
```

I have `search` function that makes an http call and returns `Observable`. I call this `search` inside of another function that should return `BehaviorSubject`. As you can see the last line `return this.watchlist$;` doesn't wait for `search` function, it just returns `BehaviorSubject` and then I just update that `watchlist$`.
What I am trying to do is to remove that last line and return `watchlist$` only when I receive a result of `search` function. 
I tried to do:

```
  getWatchlist(query: string): BehaviorSubject<IWatchlist> {
    return this.search(query)
      .subscribe((searchResults: Observable<ISearchResults>) => {
        const watchlist = formatSearchResults(searchResults);
        this.watchlist$.next(watchlist);
        return this.watchlist$;
      });
  }
```

but I've got an error: `Type Observable<BehaviorSubject<IWatchlist>>` is not assignable to type ` so how can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's only curiosity, I would like explain me because you want to return a BehaivorSubject. It's not better return a simple Observable?

Answer (score 0):

the this.search(query).subscribe(...) method return an Subscription while you must return a BehaviorSubject. secondary you should not return anything from subscribe events. you must instantiate a new BehaviorSubject and return that from getWatchlist() method and in subscribe event you should set BehaviorSubject by next() method.